# Float calculation errors

Tags: c#

in C#

```
float ratio = 185 / srcRect.Width;
```

where `srcRect.Width = 400`

returns `0` where it should return `0.45`...

min value for float is `-3.40282347E+38` so how is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are performing an integer division and hence `185/srcRect.Width` will return 0. You will need to change the expression to

```
float ratio = 185.0f / srcRect.Width;
```

Comment: float ratio = 185.0 / srcRect.Width;

Comment: gimel - that won't work as written - the RHS is type double, which can't be assigned to a float without a cast.

Answer (score 0):

185 is an integer literal, and so the division performed is integer division.

To perform a float division, use 185.0 or 185.0f instead (the former is a double, the latter is float)

Answer (score 0):

The "f" or "d" suffixes may be added to literal numbers to turn them into floats or doubles respectively.

Like so:

```
float ratio = 185f / srcRect.Width;
```

note that "185.0" is actually a double unless it also has the "f" suffix.